# Google Tag Manager - Split single URL parameter into multiple custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have our Google AdWords campaigns and adgroups naming conventions set up in a predictable fashion. For instance utm_campaign will be "Description-Topic-Segment-Audience" and the adgroup will be "Targeting Tactic-Adgroup Topic-Adgroup Subtopic".

Currently I have a number of our query parameters pushed into custom dimensions via Google Tag Manager using a Universal Analytics tag.

Inside that tag are the Custom Dimensions mapping. The index will be a static variable we've set up ("CD - Index 1" with a value of 1, "CD - Index 2" with a value of 2, etc.) and the dimension value will other variables we have that use the Query Keys. So in the tag the table looks something like:

Index     |         Dimension Value
{{CD - Index 20}}  {{CD - 20 - Value - Ad Used}}
{{CD - Index 21}}  {{CD - 21 - Value - Ad Matchtype}}

When setting up the dimension value variables, I select the variable type as URL, the component type to Query, and the Query Key to be whatever parameter I'm trying to pass along. This allows me to strip them from our URLs in the views inside GA while still preserving the data and allowing us to slice and dice by various things.

Is there a way to parse a single query parameter into two or three separate chunks that could be put into their own custom dimension?

Thanks in advance!

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom Javascript variables like

```
function () { return {{your_url_query_variable}}.split("separator");}
```

This variable will return an array of parameters that are divided by separator in your_url_query_variable.

You can store each element of this array in different custom dimensions like {{my_custom_js}}[0] for first element and so on.